# append $ in html table in specific column in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have  a html table tbl1 I have 3 column which is generated in json response. ID count and value.I want to append $ in value column in tbody

```js
$('#tbl1 tbody tr').each(function(){
 console.log($('td:nth-child(3)').text().prepend('$'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1">
  <thead>
   <tr class="hidden1"><th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Opportunity</th>
   <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Count</th>
   <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Value</th>
   </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>25818992</td>  // $25818992
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Total</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>25818992</td> //$25818992
      </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: .text() is a string

Comment: you don't need to get the div value and prepend. just prepend the new string.

$('td:nth-child(3)').prepend('$')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop

You cannot prepend to a string

Here I am using the [text function](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```js
$('#tbl1 tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').text(function() { return '$'+this.textContent });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1">
  <thead>
   <tr class="hidden1"><th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Opportunity</th>
   <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Count</th>
   <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Value</th>
   </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>25818992</td>  <!--  $25818992 -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Total</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>25818992</td> <!-- $25818992 -->
      </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

or use CSS [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `javascript` or `jquery` for that. You can achieve that by adding simple CSS like this:

```css
td.dollar:before {
    content: "$";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="hidden1">
            <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Opportunity</th>
            <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Count</th>
            <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td class="dollar">25818992</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td class="dollar">25818992</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `text(function)` method as follows:

```js
$('#tbl1 tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').text(function() {
     return '$' + $(this).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1">
  <thead>
   <tr class="hidden1"><th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Opportunity</th>
   <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Count</th>
   <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Value</th>
   </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>25818992</td>  // $25818992
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Total</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>25818992</td> //$25818992
      </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Guess you typed faster than I did!